# Moodle - Override core function in theme or plugin

Tags: php, function, class, moodle, overriding

I'm trying to reduce core patches in a moodle-instance. There where a lot of renderer-related patches, that I could move to the theme.

Now, I am stuck with functions in e.g. `lib/datalib.php`.

Is it possible to override core functions beside output renderers in moodle 2.6 on plugin or theme base? If so, how can one do?

Comment: Can you give an example of a core function you would like to overwrite?

Comment: For example `get_courses_search` in `lib/datalib.php`